# When will Windows 10 be released?

Tags: insider-preview, windows-10-mobile

I'm subscribed to the *[Preview for Developers](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/devpreview)* program, but I'm in the dark about the next big OS version for my phone (which is currently a Lumia 1520).

We know that Windows 10 will be on every device ([The Verge](http://www.theverge.com/2014/10/1/6877165/microsoft-teases-windows-10-phone-and-xbox-interface), [Microsoft's Press event](http://news.microsoft.com/windows10story/)), but apart from seeing what will probably eventually come to my phone, I'm left with the question of *when*.

What are the dates for the preview and alpha versions of Windows 10 for phones? What's the best channel of information to find out as soon as such things are available?

Comment: Keep in mind that you will need the Windows Insider app (http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=ed2b1421-6414-4544-bd8d-06d58ee402a5), not the PFD app to install Win10.

Comment: Although my question has been answered, I'm still waiting for the Windows 10 for phones preview to be released for some models like the Lumia 1520 which is the model of my phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Release date of Windows 10 Mobile](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/10069/release-date-of-windows-10-mobile)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Windows 10 has been released for the following devices in March 2016:

- Lumia 1520
- Lumia 930
- Lumia 830
- Lumia 730/735
- Lumia 640/640 XL
- Lumia 635/636/638 (1 GB)
- Lumia 540
- Lumia 535/532
- Lumia 430/435
- BLU Win HD w510u and Win HD LTE x150q
- MCJ Madosma Q501

To get started, you'll need to download the [Windows 10 Upgrade Advisor app](http://aka.ms/W10MUpgradeAdvisor). Note that actual availability of the update for your phone is dependent on carrier approval.

For more information, see the following links:

- [Windows 10 is here for your phone](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-mobile-upgrade) (Microsoft.com)
- [Upgrading existing Windows Phone 8.1 devices to Windows 10 Mobile](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/03/17/upgrading-existing-windows-phone-8-1-devices-to-windows-10-mobile) (Windows Blog)
- [Windows 10 Mobile Insider Device Rollout FAQ](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/windows-10-mobile-insider-device-rollout-faq/9861c093-fe98-482e-850d-7ca86433bd7d) (Microsoft Community)
- [Microsoft (Finally) Ships Windows 10 Mobile Upgrade for Windows Phone 8.1](https://www.thurrott.com/mobile/windows-phone/65393/microsoft-finally-ships-windows-10-mobile-upgrade-for-windows-phone-8-1) (Thurrott.com)

As for other phone models, according to [this AAWP article](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/news/item/21318_Windows_10_Mobile_finally_come.php), it's seeming more and more likely that anything from the Lumia x20 series (520, 920 and so on), as well as phones with less than 1 GB of RAM, will not be able to upgrade to Windows 10 Mobile. Hopefully Microsoft will clarify the situation with these phones soon.

---

As for the best channel of information, Windows 10 is such a big deal that every major news outlet, tech-related or not, will report on any significant milestones as soon as information becomes available. You'd really have to go out of your way to remain in the dark. That said, a couple of good sources to keep an eye on:

1. [Blogging Windows](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows)
2. [Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10)
3. [All About Windows Phone](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com)
4. [Thurrott.com](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10)
5. [Neowin](http://www.neowin.net/news/tags/windows_10)

Comment: The preview has apparently [now started](http://venturebeat.com/2015/02/12/microsoft-releases-windows-10-preview-for-phones/)

Comment: That's right! Currently for Lumia 630, Lumia 635, Lumia 636, Lumia 638, Lumia 730, and Lumia 830.

Comment: You may want to edit your answer; MS has said that it will be releasing in September. Also, you could perhaps get a little more specific now-- June 29 is the Windows 10 release date for PC's.

Comment: Just a note, the HTC 8x will apparently *not* get the update.