# Release date of Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile, 8.1-update-1

I'm just curious. Is the date of update to Windows 10 known?
I've just bought new phone with Windows Phone 8.1 and seller told me that I need to be prepared for update.
Will Windows 10 be heavier then WP 8.1? I mean, will Windows 10 required better specification to work smoothly?
I coudn't find any sufficient source, so maybe some of you know something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [news reports suggesting a November release](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/microsoft-announces-list-lumia-handsets-get-windows-10-mobile-upgrade-1513359), with the release expected to roll out model by model to (at least) all Lumia phones running Windows Phone 8.x in much the same way that previous updates have come.

Answer (score 4):

It's out!

Windows 10 Mobile rolling out started on March 17th 2016.

**References** :

1. [Microsoft Blog - Upgrading existing WP8.1 devices to Windows 10 Mobile](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/03/17/upgrading-existing-windows-phone-8-1-devices-to-windows-10-mobile/)
2. [Windows Central - Micosoft announces Windows 10 updates](http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-mobile-over-air-update-older-lumia-phones-launching?utm_medium=slider&utm_campaign=navigation&utm_source=wp)

Answer (score 2):

March 17, 2016: I just upgraded my Lumia 930 to Windows 10 Mobile by using the Upgrade Advisor app from [Microsoft's Windows 10 Mobile Upgrade page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-mobile-upgrade).

[image]

For this initial release, Microsoft says the phones and devices that can upgrade to Windows 10 Mobile are: Lumia 1520, 930, 640, 640XL, 730, 735, 830, 532, 535, 540, 635 1GB, 636 1GB, 638 1GB, 430, 435, BLU Win HD w510u, BLU Win HD LTE x150q, MCJ Madosma Q501.

It took over an hour to do the upgrade. Make sure you phone is plugged in so you don't run out of battery during the upgrade. Also, make space available by clearing out videos and pictures from your phone. Running out of battery or space during the upgrade could cause you problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently running the latest tech preview build (fast ring) on my lumia 625, that is not a monster with regard to hardware specs. I can tell you that so far is not as smooth as 8.1, sometimes it freezes and I have to force the shut down.
However, it has tons of new features that makes it better than 8.1; Rumors says that the new build should be out tomorrow, but it's unclear if it's the final, so stable, or something like a RTM

Comment: The final version isn't supposed to come out until December, and rumors of new builds are generally just that; rumors :)

Comment: yes, of course, but the next build is supposed to be very close to the final one; I also see turmoil in the store: updates of mail, calendar, network+, clock, office, windows insider, groove yesterday