# Windows 10 mobile update for Microsoft Lumia 535

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update, nokia-lumia-535

Is there any possibility to receive the Windows 10 mobile update on a Lumia 535?

Comment: The update was made available on March 17, 2016. See: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/10069/release-date-of-windows-10-mobile/12764#12764

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say your phone will receive the update to Windows 10 mobile, since it is *already* supported by the [Windows Mobile Insider Preview](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-supported-phones).

Comment: I have seen a downloaded the app, but you know I am scared. The developers are warning us. I dont want to lose a single data from my phone now. Hope everything goes fine for them so that we could enjoy W-10 UI ;)

Comment: @djgharphalia07 if you like stability then the best thing to do it's to wait for the official release of Windows 10 mobile. I cited the Windows Mobile Insider Preview because it reports the list of mobile phone supported and it is safe to assume that a phone supported by the Insider Preview will be supported in the official release of Windows 10 mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the list of handsets Microsoft has confirmed would receive the WIndows Phone 10 update at the time of release.

```
Lumia 430
Lumia 435
Lumia 532
Lumia 535
Lumia 540
Lumia 640
Lumia 640 XL
Lumia 735
Lumia 830
Lumia 930
```

There will be more handsets added later.

Source: [List of handsets that will support Windows Phone 10](http://www.windowsphonesearch.com/2015/08/list-of-handsets-that-will-support-windows-phone-10.html)

Comment: The list provided by the source you quoted is quite limited, since more than 30 devices are already supported by the Insider Preview. Also, the news you are referring to does not relate to any official statements or other verifiable sources

Comment: The link @mb47 provided have my phone on the list... now question is that when my phone will check for this update??? So that I can go for Windows 10. I dont want to do this manually. I want to have it like I got in my 8.1 PC.

Comment: @djgharphalia07 in order to receive the update to Windows 10 mobile you need to have installed on your phone the Lumia Denim update. Your phone will receive the update to Windows 10 mobile when it will be available, depending on your country and mobile operator, late this year.

Comment: My phone is updated with Lumia denim :) Thnq! for the information.

Comment: @ManuelDurando Yes, there are more than 30 phones that are supported by Windows Insider program, and even my Lumia 625 supports it. But Microsoft has confirmed in a blog post that these 10 smartphones will be the one that will have WP10 when it is rolled out.. ON the very first day. Google it, you will find somewhere the link to that post too.

Answer (score 1):

I am using W10M on lumia 535 and very happy with that. Although I should not ignore minor bugs but there is really no data loss or other severe bugs I suffered. Infact it is much more fluent, easy-to-use and comfortable (according to my opinion :D). If you want to update on W10M and don't want any data loss then please **Do not use insider updates**. You can easily use [Upgrade Advisor app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/store/p/upgrade-advisor/9nblggh0f5g4) for updation. Just follow screen instructions and you'll be done. I know a large number of rumors do exist about upgradation but if you follow these steps you'll be just fine. I am also attatching screenshots for your convinience.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]