# Any idea when will be Windows 10 be released to Nokia 1520?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-1520

Any idea when will be Windows 10 be released to Nokia 1520? Right now I have installed the Windows Insider preview version. It sucks big time. Lots of crashes and taking ages to load the home screen etc. Was disappointed when the phone 1520 was not included in the initial release. Eagerly waiting for the Windows 10 on my 1520.

Comment: The official Windows 10 Mobile release is supposed to be in December.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft will start rolling out Windows 10 Mobile updates to current phones in December. The Lumia 1520 is not yet on [the list of devices that will get the update first](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/windows10/), but I assume it will follow shortly after as it is quite similar in hardware to the Lumia 930.

These phones are currently scheduled to get the update in December:

- Lumia 430
- Lumia 435
- Lumia 532
- Lumia 535
- Lumia 540
- Lumia 635 (1 GB RAM)
- Lumia 640
- Lumia 640 XL
- Lumia 735
- Lumia 830
- Lumia 930

Comment: It's actually much better in hardware than most phones on the list.
It's an ugly practice by microsoft, I'll abandon WIndowsphone if I don't get my promised win10.

Comment: You'll definitely get it - worst case you install it through the Windows Insider app.

Comment: That's not good, I loose all the good stuff, lf it's good it should be officially released.I paid good box for 1520 Almost as much as iPhone now iPhone is updated my phone ....

Comment: It will be officially released. However, it's the carrier's decision to push the update - not Microsoft's. As with the iPhone, you do get screwed there as well - just think of Siri not coming to iPhone4 though there being no technical reason for it not to.

Comment: I have an unlocked phone, no carriers, no limitations just greedy company wasting money on trashed cheap phones. Hope Nokia had not given up to microsoft.

Comment: Why so mad? Your phone will get the update eventually. If you just want a place to rage then do it somewhere else...

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 10 Mobile update for Lumia 1520 and a host of other phones became available today March 17, 2016.

See: [Release date of Windows 10 Mobile](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/10069/release-date-of-windows-10-mobile/12764#12764)