# Windows 10 update for lumia 520

Tags: lumia-520

just wanted to know whether lumia 520 gonna get the windows 10 upgrade just like others , because if lumia 435 is getting the update then 520 must be getting it too. Can someone confirm on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/11663/106

Comment: That list are the phones that will get the update first. Other phones like the 520 will get it later.

Comment: Couldn't find any source that actually justified the rumors about getting the updates for 520..