# Update to Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update, nokia-lumia-525

Anyone got update to **Windows 10 Mobile** on Nokia **Lumia 525** Officially???
I tried on lumia 525 as well as 530, it shows phone is up to date.

- Current Version Windows Phone 8.1 Update (8.10.14219.341).

Comment: *not insider preview..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When will Windows 10 be released?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8775/when-will-windows-10-be-released)

Comment: asked about specific phone lumia 525.

Comment: and its the same answer for every phone version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows 10 Mobile rolling out started on March 17th 2016. Sadly, the Lumia 525 is not in the [list](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-mobile-specifications#primaryR2) for the upgrade. <s>Hopefully it will be in second phase.</s>

**Update** : May be your Lumia 525 may not recieve the update at all. As Microsoft says,

> As Windows 10 delivers significant new innovations, many older devices
>   are not able to successfully upgrade without an impact on the customer
>   experience. Our goal is to only offer the Windows 10 upgrade to
>   devices that we are confident can continue to deliver a good customer
>   experience.

**References** :

1. [List of phones getting Widows 10 update - Microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-mobile-specifications#primaryR2)
2. [Upgrading existing WP8.1 devices to Windows 10 Mobile - Microsoft Blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/03/17/upgrading-existing-windows-phone-8-1-devices-to-windows-10-mobile/)
3. [Micosoft announces Windows 10 updates - Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-mobile-over-air-update-older-lumia-phones-launching?utm_medium=slider&utm_campaign=navigation&utm_source=wp)
4. [Upgrade Advisor app - Windows store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/upgrade-advisor/9nblggh0f5g4)

Answer (score 3):

Download the app Upgrade Advisor from [here](http://aka.ms/W10MUpgradeAdvisor) to check if your Lumia is eligible for the Windows 10 update

Comment: not available...

Comment: yeah, The update is not available for Lumia 525. I have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Its (unofficially) rumoured the Windows 10 Mobile update is going to be released today (March 17). On top of that, the first wave of the update is going to affect a specific set of devices, including the 640, 640XL, and 430..etc

The Lumia 525 is going to get the update in the second wave release, possibly within the next 2 weeks

Comment: Well, the rumour proved to be accurate :)

Comment: Today is 21th March and I didn't receive the upgrade to Windows 10 yet. My Phone is Lumia 640 XL.

Comment: Me too. I have the Lumia 640XL, and its showing that I'm eligible for the upgrade, but its not available to me just yet because of my region and carrier. So i bet they are releasing it in stages, or waves as they call it.

Comment: Did you download the Upgrade Advisor app

Answer (score 1):

It was rumoured the Windows 10 Mobile update is going to be released for lumia 525 in Second wave release, but phones didn't get update in first wave release won't be running W10M any time soon.

> **References**

[Facebook : Nokia Innovations : List of Phones got update on 17th March](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=468091016722982&id=164676980397722&substory_index=0)

[Facebook : Nokia Innovations : W10 for 512mb RAM Devices](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=468084766723607&id=164676980397722&substory_index=0)

Comment: @KolappanNathan Thnx. Updated the Answer.